# How to find index path of last visible cell in collection view. but index path is random keeps changing

Tags: uicollectionview, cell, nsindexpath

I have tried the following code to find out the last visible index path from collectionview but visible cells keeps changing and i am unable to find the last visible item.

```
for cell: UICollectionViewCell in collView.visibleCells {
     // indexPath = collView.indexPathForCell(cell)!
        var visibleRect = CGRect()
        visibleRect.origin = collView.contentOffset
        visibleRect.size = collView.bounds.size
        let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.width, y: visibleRect.height)
        if  let indexPath = collView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint) //If let is
        {
            return indexPath
        } else {
            return IndexPath(row: NSNotFound, section: 0)
        }

}
```

output

```
"<NSIndexPath: 0x17422c680> {length = 2, path = 0 - 4}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0x17403e0c0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 6}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0x1742261c0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 10}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0x17422adc0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0x1742205e0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0x17422a1a0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 7}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0x174227080> {length = 2, path = 0 - 9}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0x174229b40> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}"
```

Comment: Can you show how you collection view look like?

Comment: same as photos app

Answer (score 2):

You can use `indexPathsForVisibleItems` to get an array of indexPaths of visible items in a `UICollectionView`.

```
var indexPathsForVisibleItems: [IndexPath] { get }
```

> The value of this property is an unsorted array of IndexPath objects,
>   each of which corresponds to a visible cell in the collection view.
>   This array does not include any supplementary views that are currently
>   visible. If there are no visible items, the value of this property is
>   an empty array.

Like in photos app as you specified, you will get multilple elements of `IndexPath` in the array since more than 1 elements are visible at a particular instant.

Also, I don't understand what do you mean by last visible index. Please make it more clear for any further help.

**Edit:**

**Example:**
I have created a UICollectionView with **30 cells and 1 section** in it. 
For the below screen:

[image]

I have used the below lines of code:

```
    let arrayOfVisibleItems = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.sorted()
    let lastIndexPath = arrayOfVisibleItems.last
    print("Array: ", arrayOfVisibleItems)
    print("Last IndexPath: ", lastIndexPath)
```

**Output:**

```
Array:  [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7], [0, 8], [0, 9], [0, 10], [0, 11], [0, 12], [0, 13], [0, 14], [0, 15], [0, 16], [0, 17], [0, 18], [0, 19], [0, 20]]

Last IndexPath:  Optional([0, 20])
```

Comment: I have used same as above but i want to get last item visible in collection view.like if  i have eight items visible and i want index path of eight item

Comment: If you want the last one, you can just use last property on the array, i.e., arrayOfVisibleItems.last

Comment: but i think i am wrong indexpath like i have given output pls check

Comment: I have edited the answer. Let me know if it satisfy your requirement.